# npm install from git repo fails with ENOENT

Tags: node.js, github, installation, npm

I am trying to install [one of my own packages](http://github.com/gfarrell/State.js) as follows

```
npm install --save gfarrell/state.js
```

and I'm getting the following errors ([full log here](https://gist.github.com/gfarrell/13522959f39734ac6e92)):

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install gfarrell/state.js
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'gfarrell/state.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "gfarrell/state.js"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/gideon/Code/PresenceMonitor
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.10
npm ERR! path gfarrell/state.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gideon/Code/PresenceMonitor/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Now I've tried [various solutions](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3664) including:

- `npm cache clean`
- `sudo npm cache clean`
- `rm -rf ~/.npm`
- `sudo npm install --save gfarrell/state.js`
- `npm install --save git://github.com/gfarrell/state.js.git`

but nothing has changed the error output. I can't see anything wrong with the module's [package.json](https://github.com/gfarrell/State.js/blob/master/package.json), and I haven't added anything to my local `package.json` either. I actually tried installing this package on an earlier version and it worked fine, so I just don't understand what is going wrong.

Needless to say, it's all rather frustrating. Is there something else going on that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I don't remember how, I'm afraid. But the second answer below might help?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably an authentication issue. You should add `--verbose` to the install command to se more output. You should see this line in your console output when running with verbose on:

> npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:gfarrell/state.js Permission denied (publickey).

Check if you are authenticated to Github using the following command:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

When you are authenticated correctly you should see the following output:

> Hi gfarrell! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Github has a great guide on [SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) as well as how to solve [common errors](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey).

Fix your Github authentication and the npm install will start working.

Comment: I'm already authenticated to Github (but checked just in case) so that's not the problem. Verbose flag doesn't help much, it identifies the git repo on github but just tells me `npm ERR! addLocal Could not install gfarrell/state.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue myself. Because the last "ok" line of the verbose output started with "addRemoteGit", I traced the issue to a function named `addRemoteGit` in the `npm` source file *cache.js* (in v1.4.9, it has now been moved into [*add-remote-git.js*](//github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/lib/cache/add-remote-git.js)). By adding a call to `log.verbose(p)`, I found out `npm` could not write to `~/.npm/_git-remotes/`.

Basically it was a permission problem: my `~/.npm` directory contained files & directories owned by `root`. I solved the issue by simply running:

```
sudo find ~/.npm -exec chown $USER:$USER {} \;
```